# The experience you requested uses Expo SDK v(null), but this copy of Expo Client requires at least v35.0.0

Tags: react-native, expo

I decided to return to an Expo app I was developing last year and was using expo-sdk:v33.0.0 and it was working.
I tried to use a solution of Squirrl from similar question, but still no luck. Tried removing node_modules and yarn_install. Here's my package.json:

```
enter 
"dependencies": {
 "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
 "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
 "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.1.1",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.3",
 "axios": "^0.18.1",
 "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
 "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
 "expo": "^33.0.0",
 "expo-font": "~5.0.1",
 "lodash": "^4.17.15",
 "native-base": "^2.13.1",
 "react": "16.8.3",
 "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
 "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.2.1",
 "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
 "react-native-paper": "^3.6.0",
 "react-native-platform-touchable": "^1.1.1",
 "react-native-reanimated": "1.0.1",
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
 "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
 "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.1.0",
 "react-native-tab-view": "^2.13.0",
 "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
 "react-redux": "^5.1.0",
 "redux": "^4.0.1",
 "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
 "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
 "save": "^2.4.0",
 "victory-native": "^30.6.0"
"devDependencies": {
 "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
 "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
 "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0"
```

The app was working with these dependencies that time.
1st issue is that error says Expo SDK v(null). But version is specified in both package.json and app.json.
2nd issue is error says Expo client requires v35.0.0. How can i run the app without upgrading sdk from v33 to v35

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

Run `npm i -g expo-cli` (You may have to use sudo if on a Mac. I did.) then run `expo upgrade`

Follow the prompts and it should work.