# Expo SDK v(null) - Expo Client requires v35.0.0

Tags: react-native, expo

I see a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969994/the-experience-you-requested-uses-expo-sdk-vnull-but-this-copy-of-expo-client), but I don't want to install expo-cli globally. I want my project's packages to be dictated by the package.json. This way when it's shared, nobody needs to do any other extra configuration. My package.json is:

```js
{
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "upgrade": "expo upgrade",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "expo-cli": "^3.22.3",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^31.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my app.json

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "stuff",
    "description": "A very interesting project.",
    "slug": "stuff",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

Ok after spending countless hours on this, it's fixed. I basically just did what was asked and changed `expo` to 35.0.0 and have react-native point to sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz. Changed the version to 35.0.0 in app.json as well

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
expo upgrade
```

or you can find your version documentation from
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/
in individual page has instruction
https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-ab6cd30ca2ee

Below 37.0.0 support

```
expo update 35.0.0
```

this code